# clearTimeout with multiple timeouts within

Tags: javascript

I have ajax to load pages within my site, but these pages contain certain scripts including timeouts.

If the user enters the page and exits by entering this loop, the page timeout has not finished executing, causing several timeouts (and timeouts have a loop to execute them again)

There is my code:

```
//"REMOVE" IF TIMEOUT IS RUNNING
var timer1;
var timer2;
var timer3;

if (timer1 !== undefined) {
    clearTimeout(timer1);
    timer1 = '';
}

if (timer2 !== undefined) {
    clearTimeout(timer2);
    timer2 = '';
}

if (timer3 !== undefined) {
    clearTimeout(timer3);
    timer3 = '';
}

//LOOP WHEN PAGE LOADS
Loop();

function Loop() {
    var randTimeout1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100)) + 40;

    timer1 = setTimeout(function () {
        //EXECUTE ONE FUNCTION

        var randTimeout2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100)) + 40;

        timer2 = setTimeout(function () {
            //EXECUTE ANOTHER FUNCTION

            var randTimeout3 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100)) + 45;

            timer3 = setTimeout(function () {
                //EXECUTE ANOTHER FUNCTION

                var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 200)) + 6500;
                setTimeout(function () { /*EXECUTE LOOP AGAIN */ Loop(); }, rand);

            }, randTimeout3);

        }, randTimeout2)

    }, randTimeout1)
}
```

But the code below the remove comment

> clearTimeout

doesn't work with timeouts within timeout

Comment: Just call clearTimeout on those variables without check.

Comment: You can call `clearTimeout` at the beginning of your `loop` function I believe

Comment: Your clearTimeouts are executed at *page load*. You need to execute them when the page transitions.

Comment: Ivan Cherviakov solution solved my question, thanks.